# Saving and Reading Image Array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I want to save my image array 'DtaAryVar' in 'NSUserDefaults' or in 'document directory' or in 'core data'. Can anyone please tell me step by step what is best and simple way to store it also 'UIImage' array(that contains 20 images) to 'NSData' conversion. My 'DtaAryVar' contains 20 images. I have tried below method that i found from stack overflow but getting an error. Please help me.

```
var DtaAryVar: [NSData]()
 convert array of NSData to Data and store

let DtaZipVar = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(DtaAryVar)

let DftSdbVal = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
DftSdbVal.setObject(DtaZipVar, forKey: "ImageKey")

get back data by

var DtaZipVar = DftSdbVal.valueForKey("ImageKey")
var DtaAryVar = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(DtaZipVar) as! [NSData]

let ImjAryVar = [UIImage]()
for DtaIdxVar in DtaAryVar
{
    ImjAryVar.append(UIImage(data : DtaIdxVar))
}
```

> **Error**
>   Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type 'NSData.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> |=> U can store only NSData in userDefautls or coreData not [NSData]
>
> |=> If u r storing in core data, assign the attribute type as binary

|*| Add Row from Raw data to CoreData :

```
let NewRowDtaVar = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("NamTbl", inManagedObjectContext: ContxtVar)
NewRowDtaVar.setValue(ImgDtaVar, forKey: "NamKol")
AppDgtVar.saveContext()
```

|*| Get Row data from CoreData :

```
let GetDtaAryReqVar = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "NamTbl")
GetDtaAryReqVar.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
GetDtaAryReqVar.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NamKol = TstTxt")

let ImgDtaVar = NSData()
do
{
    let ReqResAryVar: Array  = try ContxtVar.executeFetchRequest(GetDtaAryReqVar)
    
    if(ReqResAryVar.count > 0)
    {
        for ReqResVar in ReqResAryVar
        {
            ImgDtaVar = ReqResVar.valueForKey("NamKol") as! NSData!
        }
    }
}
catch let ErrVar as NSError
{
    print("Fetch failed: \(ErrVar.localizedDescription)")
}
```

---

Add the below extension functions outside any of your viewController class and try accordingly

```
extension UIImage
{

//|*| Convert Image NSData Arry to UIImage Array

    func CnvDtaAryTooImjAryFnc(ImjDtaAryPsgVar: [NSData])-> [UIImage]
    {
        var ImjAryVar = [UIImage]()
        for DtaIdxVar in ImjDtaAryPsgVar
        {
            ImjAryVar.append(UIImage(data : DtaIdxVar)!)
        }
        return ImjAryVar
    }

//|*| Convert Image NSData to UIImage Array

    func CnvDtaTooImjAryFnc(ImjDtaPsgVar: NSData)-> [UIImage]
    {
        let ImjAryVar = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(ImjDtaPsgVar) as! [NSData]
        return CnvDtaAryTooImjAryFnc(ImjAryVar)
    }

//|*| Convert UIImage Array to Image NSData Arry  

    func CnvImjAryTooDtaAryFnc(ImjDtaPsgVar: [UIImage], ImjTyp ImjTypPsgVar: String?="Jpg")-> [NSData]
    {
        var ImjDtaAryVar = [NSData]()
        for DtaIdxVar in ImjDtaPsgVar
        {
            if(ImjTypPsgVar == "Png")
            {
                if let GetImjDtaVar = UIImagePNGRepresentation(DtaIdxVar)
                {
                    ImjDtaAryVar.append(GetImjDtaVar)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if let GetImjDtaVar = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(DtaIdxVar, 1)
                {
                    ImjDtaAryVar.append(GetImjDtaVar)
                }
            }
        }
        return ImjDtaAryVar
    }

//|*| Convert UIImage Array to Image NSData 

    func CnvImjAryTooDtaFnc(ImjDtaPsgVar: [UIImage], ImjTyp ImjTypPsgVar: String?="Jpg")-> NSData
    {
        let ImjDtaAryVar = CnvImjAryTooDtaAryFnc(ImjDtaPsgVar, ImjTyp : ImjTypPsgVar)
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(ImjDtaAryVar)
    }
}
```